# asp.net GridView Data manipulation

Tags: asp.net

I have GridView which displays data like this

```
Name      Type     Description

abc       1         test
xyz       2         test
mno       1         another test
```

This Data is retreived from sqldatasource.

Question: I want to display type Name instead of ID Eg( if type =1 then it should display "Truck" and if Type = 2 it should display "Driver") I have only 2 types(Truck and Driver)

Can anyone please help me in this?

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the current `BoundField` you have for the "Type" column to a `TemplateField`.

I'm assuming you are not setting the `GridView` `AutoGenerateColumns` to true.

```
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Type</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Type").ToString()) == 1 ? "Truck" : "Driver" %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And would that be possible, If I want to call a method, which will be returning the result value?